# Schedules em grande escala

Tags: javascript, node.js

Possuo um serviço que será utilizado em grande escala, e uma de suas especificações é executar uma alteração no banco de dados depois de 10 minutos da requisição HTTP chegar ao servidor.

Eu poderia utilizar um `setTimeOut`, mas devido a quantidade de acessos esperado eu acredito que atingiria o limite de memória do Node eventualmente.

Preciso de sugestões de como implementar esse requisito eficientemente.

Comment: Enfileire as requisições e mantenha um conjunto de processos locais(threads) ou remotos(outro servidor) que atenderão essas solicitação enfileiradas no primeiro caso desafogando o processo de sua aplicação e no segundo caso desafogando o processador do host de sua aplicação. Uma ou outra abordagem depende da magnitude da sua operação.